# JavaScript prototype creation in constructor

Tags: javascript, oop, prototype

What happens in memory when you add to an object's prototype in the constructor?  Does it get it recreated every time you make a new object?

For example:

```
function Foo(){
  Foo.prototype.bar = function() {
    console.log("bar func called");
  }
}    
var x = new Foo();
x.bar();
var y = new Foo();
y.bar();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "nature" of the code doesn't matter, it's executed every time you call it. This means that yes, every time you call `new Foo()` the function `bar` of the prototype is reassigned.

This also means that every `Foo` object out there get a new `bar` method, even those that already existed.

Comment: And, you may want to add that this is a bad way to write code.  The prototype should be assigned to once not repeatedly.

Answer (score 0):

All code that you put in a function runs every time you call that function, even if said code assigns a property of a prototype.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it does. The creation code will be executed each time you instantiate Foo.